# How can I seal a foundation vent?

Tags: foundation, vent, crawlspace

I have a foundation vent that lets water into the basement and leads to flooding when it rains. I have plenty other vents and so I would like to completely close this one. The water comes in because the water collects in the flower bed outside the house.

I want to seal it. And I am looking for suggestions on how to do it. I am a new homeowner. Don’t know much about all this.

[image]

Comment: Have you got a photo of the outside ?

Answer (score 15):

I'd suggest that the problem is the flower bed, not the vent. Grade should be reduced and sloped properly to prevent the problem. Consider rain gutters in the area. You could also switch to a flower *box* to keep soil away from the foundation. Obviously the vent was installed to provide fresh air to the crawl space, preventing mold and decay, and it should probably be retained.

- [Soil grade is above foundation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/97110/35141)
- [Is it a good idea to use dirt to grade away from foundation?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/113057/35141)
- [What's the best way to get grade below foundation wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/78440/35141)
- [Questions about rain gutters](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adiy.stackexchange.com%20rain%20gutter%20installation&sca_esv=597261711)

If you do want to close it, the usual course of action is to remove the vent and install concrete as per the rest of the wall. This could be in the form of bricks or blocks mortared into place rather than poured concrete, but it would provide a good basis for a waterproof coating.

- [How to plug hole in foundation?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/36241/35141)
- [Repairing above-ground gaps and holes in foundation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/179318/35141)
- [How to patch this hole in exposed foundation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/273539/35141)
- [What kind of mortar do I need to use?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/257828/35141)

You could also mount a rot-resistant panel of some sort (vinyl, metal) into the opening and caulk it to the existing concrete or fasten it to the surface with a neoprene gasket using concrete screws.

- [What's the standard way to mount wooden board to concrete wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/133371/35141)
- [Mounting a glass panel on drywall over concrete](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/152167/35141)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Can you also help with how to do the first part. What does grade mean and how to change the slope? 

On your second part can you tell me any products or pictures that would help me look for things

Comment: There are many good questions and answers on this site covering both topics. Your question is spreading in scope. Please take the [tour] and see the [help]. Post a new question if you've searched and not found what you need.

Comment: The first step would be to lower the level of the flower bed by removing soil and/or place a drain in the flower bed to prevent the pooling of water next to the foundation. We need a picture of the foundation on the outside. If there a roof gutter drain that is disgorging water that is pooling then add an extension to direct the water out away from the foundation. Sealing the opening would not be the best option to prevent water flowing in. The water should not be allowed to pool in the first place.

Comment: @Apna Grade refers to two things. 1. [Soil gradation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soil_gradation). A flower bed (and just about all landscaping) will have multiple grades, you can roughly think of them as layers. A rough grade for drainage and flow of excess water. A top grade over it (sometimes called a final grade or finish grade) with topsoil. 2. Slope and height. Rough grading is getting the overall shape and slope in place. When done incorrectly, basements will flood. Remove the excess material, put in a new rough grade low enough and put finer grade over it. Basically, lower the bed.